# When should I consider retaining full capitalization?

Tags: .net, naming-conventions

It appears that quite a number of .NET Framework classes seem to deviate from [Capitalization Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx):

- System.Text.**ASCIIEncoding**
- System.Text.**UTF7Encoding**
- System.Text.**UTF8Encoding**
- System.Text.**UTF32Encoding**
- System.Security.Cryptography.**SHA256CryptoServiceProvider**
- System.Security.Cryptography.**RSAOAEPKeyExchangeFormatter**

> The PascalCasing convention, used for all identifiers except parameter names, capitalizes the first character of each word (including acronyms over two letters in length).

Is there a meaningful explanation that can help me decide when I should consider retaining full capitalization of acronyms?